# How to remove GPG key from GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with my GPG key. I removed my GPG key from my PC and my account and now when I want to commit changes from my computer it says:

gpg: skipped "name ": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

So how can I unset it from  Git?

Comment: Perhaps `git config --global --unset user.signingkey`?

Comment: It was first thing I did. But thanks.

Comment: Git configuration has 2 scopes: global scope and project scope. My command unset the global one, but you might also need to unset the project one. Another thing that might help: disabling the automatic GPG sign for commit `git config commit.gpgsign false` for both global and project scope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remote a *GPG* key from GitHub, go to https://github.com/settings/keys and under `GPG keys`, select the one and remove it.

To remove it from Git, I believe @Mincong Huang's suggestion might work:

```
git config --global --unset user.signingkey
```

Then you can globally disable the *GPG* sign in key for commits

```
git config --global commit.gpgsign false
```

Comment: Let's say I have a GPG key that I used to sign commits on Github. If I delete that key from my GH account, will my previous commits still be signed?

Comment: @giograno Yes, they will continue to be signed.